# Querying records created in this month using codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, activerecord

I have following table

```
myTable (id{INT},title{VARCHAR}, created{DATE(y-m-d)});
```

I am using following code to query the number of records that have been created with in this month using codeigniter's active records. But i am getting an error

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('myTable');
$this->db->where('created=', Month(Date));            
$query =  $this->db->get();
return $query->num_rows();
```

My question is what is the correct way of doing this using CI active records. Could someone please help me.

Comment: What error you getting?

Comment: It says function Month is undefined. What i dont know is that how to filter records that has been created within this month

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you want to compare month only,you should take month(`created`) in query rather than `created` only.

```
$query  = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `myTable` where month(`created`) =  date('m')");
```

Check if this is working for you.

Comment: Thank you for this . I want an active record solution. anyway upvoted for mysql approch

Comment: For that you just need to update where

$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('myTable');
$this->db->where('month(created)=',date('m'));            
$query =  $this->db->get();
return $query->num_rows();

Answer (score 9):

This will do:

```
 $this->db->where('month(created)', date('m'));
```

Comment: What just happened? This was chosen best answear, then changed? Are you kidding?